# What exactly does self variable do? How do I use it in this case?

Tags: python, class, self

I've created a class called `Colors()` that has some lists defined in it. I have a method in it called `set_alpha()` that has to append the index 3 of the list with the parameter provided.

Here's the block of code:

```
class Colors():
    self.red = (255, 0, 0)
    self.blue = (0, 0, 255)
    self.green = (0, 255, 0)
    def set_alpha(self, alpha):
        self[3] = alpha
```

I knew this would be wrong before I even typed it because I do not understand the
`self` thing well. It gives an error saying self is not defined. What I want the result of my class is something like this -

When I do-

```
Colors.red.set_alpha(128)
```

I want red to become-

```
red = (255, 0, 0, 128)
```

Please explain 
EDIT: How do I solve my problem now? How do I use the method `set_alpha()` on a variable in the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `self` represents the instance of a class object, here of class `Colors`. For example:

```
c = Colors()
c.a_method()
```

When I call `a_method()` the variable self of the method will be `c`, considering `a_method` being defined as:

```
def a_method(self):
    """A method that does something."""
    pass
```

Now, in your case you would most probably want to have the `red`, `green` , `blue` and `alpha` attributes simply as integers, not as tuples:

```
class Colors:
    def __init__(red, green, blue, alpha=255):
         self.red = red
         self.blue = blue
         self.green = green
         self.alpha = alpha

    def set_alpha(alpha):
         self.alpha = alpha
```

Additionally, on class level the variable `self` is not defined so when you write `self.red` you will get an undefined error.